# Primefaces con JSF enviar datos de una dataTable a otra dataTable

Tags: primefaces

Buen dia, estoy intentando hacer una cotización con los productos que se encuentran en la siguiente dataTable

```
    <p:dataTable value="#{productoController.listaProducto}" var="c" id="productos">
    <p:column headerText="Codigo" filterBy="#{c.id_producto}">
        <h:outputText value="#{c.id_producto}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Descripción" filterBy="#{c.descripcion_producto}" >
        <h:outputText value="##{c.descripcion_producto}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Presentación" filterBy="#{c.presentacion}">
        <h:outputText value="#{c.presentacion}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Tipo" filterBy="#{c.tipo_producto}">
        <h:outputText value="#{c.tipo_producto}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Núm.Bodega" filterBy="#{c.numeroBodega_producto}">
        <h:outputText value="##{c.numeroBodega_producto}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Cantidad" filterBy="#{c.cantidad_producto}">
        <h:outputText value="##{c.cantidad_producto}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Marca" filterBy="#{c.marca_producto}">
        <h:outputText value="#{c.marca_producto}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Precio" filterBy="#{c.precio_producto}">
        <h:outputText value="#{c.precio_producto}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Editar" exportable="false">
        <p:commandButton  value="Seleccionar"
                          onclick="PF('producto').hide();"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Y pasar el producto seleccionado a la siguiente dataTable

```
    <p:dataTable id="tablaProductosCotizacion" emptyMessage="No se han agregado productos">
        <p:column headerText="Codigo Producto">
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Precio Producto">
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

En mi aplicación se debe poder crear cotizaciones con cualquier numero de productos elegido por el usuario y estos productos aparescan en la dataTable #tablaProductosCotizacion.
Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Hola @ÃlëxišRubio he realizado el ejemplo un poco a memoria, pero el proceso es el siguiente activar la selección múltiple en la primera tabla y guardas las selecciones en un lista secundaria, colocas un botón que  actualice la segunda tabla o ejecute un método que procese los datos y después actualizar la segunda tabla, puedes basarte en los ejemplos de primefaces https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{productoController.listaProducto}" var="c" id="productos" selection="#{productoController.listaProductoSeleccionados}" rowKey="#{c.id_producto}">
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
    <p:column headerText="Codigo" filterBy="#{c.id_producto}">
        <h:outputText value="#{c.id_producto}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Descripción" filterBy="#{c.descripcion_producto}" >
        <h:outputText value="##{c.descripcion_producto}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Presentación" filterBy="#{c.presentacion}">
        <h:outputText value="#{c.presentacion}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Tipo" filterBy="#{c.tipo_producto}">
        <h:outputText value="#{c.tipo_producto}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Núm.Bodega" filterBy="#{c.numeroBodega_producto}">
        <h:outputText value="##{c.numeroBodega_producto}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Cantidad" filterBy="#{c.cantidad_producto}">
        <h:outputText value="##{c.cantidad_producto}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Marca" filterBy="#{c.marca_producto}">
        <h:outputText value="#{c.marca_producto}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Precio" filterBy="#{c.precio_producto}">
        <h:outputText value="#{c.precio_producto}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Editar" exportable="false">
        <p:commandButton  value="Seleccionar"
                          onclick="PF('producto').hide();"/>
    </p:column>
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton process="productos" update=":form:tablaProductosCotizacion" icon="pi pi-search" value="Cotizar" />
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>

<p:dataTable id="tablaProductosCotizacion" value="#{productoController.listaProductoSeleccionados}" var="p" emptyMessage="No se han agregado productos">
    <p:column headerText="Codigo Producto">
        <h:outputText value="#{p.id_producto}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Precio Producto">
        <h:outputText value="#{p.precio_producto}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```